# What are Rek's intentions in the beginning of Legend?

Tags: drenai-series

At the beginning of *Legend*, Regnak "Rek" says farewell to Horeb at leaves to South. He has to go through the Gaven Forest (full of Reinard's bandits crew) were he meets Virae and starts his story.

But what were his plans, where was he heading before meeting Virae? Why going South through a dangerous forest full of dangerous bandits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure he has any particular plans, other than getting as far away from the Nadir invasion route as possible.

It is worth noting the name he is known by in the start of the book even by the Monks of the Temple of the Thirty, Rek the Wanderer which implies that he is known to go off into the wilderness by himself quite often.